# Issue centering ul element within div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am running into an issue centering my `ul` element within my div. I used the `margin: 0 auto` technique, but it isn't working in this scenario. In addition, I always had a question related to whether setting the width to a `ul` element within a `div` was necessary to use the `margin: 0 auto` is there a way around this?

html:

```
<div class="col-3-12">
            <div class="sidebar-personal-information">
                <div id="sidebar-social-media">
                    <ul id="sidebar-social-media-list">
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/linkedin.png"></li>
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/twitter.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

css:

```
.sidebar-personal-information {
    background-color: #00a8df;
}

#sidebar-social-media {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: center;
}
ul#sidebar-social-media-list{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



#sidebar-social-media ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

[image: Enclosing Div]

[image: Ul Div]

Comment: try text:align-center to #sidebar-social-media or ul#sidebar-social-media-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sc7obvm/)
By adding `text-align: center`to `#sidebar-social-media` in your CSS the problem should be solved.

Credits go to **Vitorino Fernandes**, I would like to comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hey @Thomas More. The both of you are correct.That worked. Is there any specific reason why this would be, despite the fact that they are images instead of text?

Comment: @cphill I think it's because you gave the list a width of 100%